# PushPlugin source issue in Android -- attempting PhoneGap push notifications

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm trying to plug the *PushPlugin* plugin (http://goo.gl/xn8z4) in to my Android PhoneGap application.

I'm getting stuck at this point here http://goo.gl/b03fs.  I'm 80-93% confident that I have the Java source in the right place.

Java's trying to import `org.apache.cordova.example.R` but can't seem to find it.  I'm suspicious that as soon as it starts importing it, I'm golden.

I'm working with the Cordova 2.2 jar/classes.

Here's where I'm seeing the package import failure: http://goo.gl/U3VlI

This is where the code is trying to talk to the object from the package that's failing to load http://goo.gl/LJbLb

It feels like this is a simple solution, but again, my skull appears to be excessively thick this afternoon.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Boy, how I wish I had attempted this earlier: the solution to this one was to update the Cordova(PhoneGap) library to v 2.3.

There's a bloody spot on my head and nearby wall that I hope this post can help someone else sidestep.